# Satellite ground station site selection

Tags: qgis, elevation, azimuth

I want to carry out suitability of a few identified Area of Interests to set up satellite ground station. The main requirement of the ground station is: it needs to have visibility above 10 degree elevation angle in all azimuth direction(0 - 360 degree).

The output I want is to have angle of obstruction, and angle formed by the line from the ground station pointing to the obstructing terrain (minimum visible elevation angle), for all azimuth direction with say 5 degree azimuth step size.

I have 10m DEM file of the AoI.

I have tried in QGIS using viewshed analysis, elevation profile, etc to no avail. How can I carry out this exercise in QGIS only or some open source software?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, you need to report exactly what you tried, and what went wrong. We are a *problem-solving* site, so we need a problem, not just a task and an indication that what you tried didn't work.